# Prove or disprove: complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

There is this question about complex numbers that I got stuck on for a while, I'd be glad for help:

Let $$z\in\Bbb{C}$$ such that $$z^3=\bar{z^3}$$ and $$|z|=1$$

Prove or disprove the followings:
1) there are exactly 6 different numbers that make the 2 equations true.

2) there are exactly 3 rational numbers that make the 2 equations true.

3) there exists infinity amount of different numbers that make the equation $$z^3=\bar{z^3}$$ true.

4) there exists exactly 4 numbers which are making the 2 equations true and their Imaginary part is bigger than 0.

How do I approach this kind of question? Again, I'd be glad for help.

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: If $|z|=1$, then $z=e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta$.  Also, $\bar z = e^{-i \theta}$.  See if these facts help you solve the problem.

Comment: Hint: $\;|z|=1 \iff |z|^2=1 \iff z \bar z =1\,$.

Comment: Are you sure that there are 3 rational numbers satisfying this equations ? I have only 1 and -1.

Comment: @user534957 Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $z^3$ and

$$z^6=z^3\bar z^3=(|z|^2)^3=1$$ so that the solutions are the sixth roots of one.

1) Yes.

2) No, 2.

3) Yes, if the modulus isn't constrained.

4) No, $3$.

Comment: Amazing. I would have never thought about this by my own at the first time

Comment: @user534957: you need to know properties of the complex numbers. Among others, $|z|=1\iff \bar z=z^{-1}$.

Comment: Only 1 question left. Can you explain me 3? How did you determine the answer and what did you mean when you said "if the modulus isnt constrained"?

Comment: @user534957: one of the equations is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You can simply solve this equation and see if some answer fits what you've found.

It's better to use the exponential notation here: $|z|=1$ means $z=\mathrm e^{i\theta}\:$  for some $ 0\le \theta<2\pi$, and in this case $\bar z=z^{-1}$.

The equation $z^3=\bar z^{\mkern1mu3}$ translates as
$$z^3=z^{-3}\iff z^6=\mathrm{e}^{6i\theta}=1\iff \theta\equiv 0\mod  2\pi, $$
i.e. $z$ is one of the sixth roots of unity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=a+bi$ and $z*=a-bi$ ($z*$ is conjugate of $z$). We have 2 equations:
$(a+bi)^3=(a-bi)^3$
and
$a^2+b^2=1$.
Expanding the first equation:
$a^3+3bia^2 - 3ab^2- ib^3 = a^3 - 3bia^2-3ab^2 + ib^3$
Then by rearranging the terms and canceling we get:
$3bia^2=ib^3$.  Then:
$3ba^2=b^3$.
Now from the second equation we get:
$a^2 = 1- b^2$.
By plugging in, that, in the first equation we get:
$3b(1 - b^2)=b^3$.
One of the roots of this equation is $b=0$, so now we can divide the equation by $b$. Now we get:
$3 - 3b^2 = b^2$
$4b^2 - 3 = 0$
$b = √3/2$ or $b = -√3/2$.
Now for b = 0 we get a=1 or -1.
For b = √3/2 we get a = 1/2 or -1/2.
For b = -√3/2 we get a = 1/2 or -1/2.
So we get 6 answers:$1;-1;1/2+√3/2i;1/2-√3/2i;-1/2+√3/2i;-1/2-√3/2i$
I hope my answer will help you. If something is not clear, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We need to solve

$$z^3=\bar{z^3} \qquad |z|=1\iff e^{3i\theta}=e^{-3i\theta}\iff e^{6i\theta}=1$$